# RewriteRule htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good day,

I've been searching here and Google for a solution to our issue. We currently work on a website and we need to rewrite 2 "dirty" URLs. Here's one of the 2 we've been working on and it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^galerie-photos/ilvanaa$ galerie-photos/?section=17 [L]
```

Basically, we want to rewrite it so ?section=17 is replaced by something cleaner.

Everything in the htaccess is set as our Redirect 301 work fine. We tried any variant possible. I couldn't find the adequate solution for this issue on the forum and I've spent time meticulously read and went over this (http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) and this (http://www.webrankinfo.com/dossiers/techniques/tutoriel-url-rewriting). Yet none of the solutions worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: If my question isn't clear, please tell me how to make it better. Thanks

Comment: What is the url the user puts in, what is the url the user should end up seeing and what is the filepath to the file that should be shown?

Comment: The user currently sees this:

The website currently shows this: http://www.aubergelamara.com/galerie-photos/?section=17

We want to "clean up" the url and have visitors see this instead: http://www.aubergelamara.com/galerie-photos/photos-ilvana

Answer (score 0):

Because "photos-ilvana" isn't in the original url, you'll need to use a router-page that retrieves that from (for example) a database. The other way around, you need a way to translate this seo-title back to a section number. Because the first rewriterule doesn't have a query string in the 2nd argument, the original query string is used (which we want).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^section=
RewriteRule ^galerie-photos/?$ /galerie-photos/routeToSeo.php [L]
RewriteRule ^galerie-photos/(.*)/?$ /galerie-photos/index.php?seo=$1 [L]
```

routeToSeo.php

```
<?php
  $seo = translateSeoToId( $_GET['section'] ); //Remember to protect against sql injection
  header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
  header( "Location: /galerie-photos/$seo" );
?>
```

In index.php you might want to translate to an id, or directly search your database for the seo-title you store in there, and skip the step with the section altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Will give this a try. Appreciate the help.